# Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Core Razor - can't switch to Razor mode inside HTML element

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2017

This is a simplified excerpt of my code (dynamic CSHTML page), written in Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Core Razor:

```
<option value="SomeValue" class="@(x.Completed ? "Completed" : "")">SomeText</option>
<option value="SomeValue" @(x.Completed ? "class=\"Completed\"" : "")">SomeText</option>
```

The first line works fine, but in the second the engine doesn't switch to Razor mode at @ symbol, as it should (I can easily see that in code coloring, which you don't see here). It seems that @ is a legal character in HTML5 attribute names, but what am I supposed to do?

An answer to a similar question is proposed [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2100538.aspx?How%20to%20embedded%20razor%20if%20statement%20inside%20a%20html%20element%20), but in my Visual Studio it doesn't work. The reason why I need this programming logic is to greatly simplify the code (which is not obvious from only 2 lines I presented here).

Comment: You can try this way: `<option value="SomeValue" @(x.Completed  ? "class=Completed" : "class=NonCompleted")>SomeText</option>`

Comment: The result is the same - it doesn't work. The problem is how to tell the Razor engine that @ character means "Razor" and not "HTML tag attribute name".

Comment: I tested it on my machine and it works...weird...

Comment: Which version of dev. env. do you have, mine is Visual Studio 2017 15.4.5 ASP.NET Core 2.0 ?